# How can I array results from multiple checkbox post values?

Tags: php, html, arrays

I am building a fruit store website.

Currently, I wanna ask to my customers what kind of fruits they love.

So, I created several checkbox options for them.

```
<form action='customer_favorite' method='POST'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='chk[]' value='banana' />
  <input type='checkbox' name='chk[]' value='mango' />
  <input type='checkbox' name='chk[]' value='apple' />
  <input type='checkbox' name='chk[]' value='orange' />
  <input type='checkbox' name='chk[]' value='kiwi' />
<input type='submit' value='submit' />
```

- I don't know how many checkboxes they will check.
- When it posts to my server, I want to get the result like this.

  ```
  apple, orange, kiwi
  ```
- second customer would choose four of them.

  ```
  banana, mango, apple, orange
  ```

and I will put this data into my db like this.

```
$data = array(
'fav_fruits' = $this->input->post('chk')
);    

$this->db->insert('customer', $data)
```

The problem is that I can't get result 'apple, orange, kiwi' like this.

- we don't know how many checkbox values will be there.
- I want to array values like this 'apple, orange, kiwi'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the clear text values in your DB (not normalized), you can do this:

```
$data = array(
    'fav_fruits' = json_encode($this->input->post('chk'))
);    
$this->db->insert('customer', $data)
```

EDIT:
 changed teh original `implode()` to `json_encode` due to @Madmartigan comment

Comment: Addition: How do you expect the database to know how to seperate the array in words seperated by comma. (array => apple, banana, mango)? imploding it first will domathat for you.

Comment: Other possibly better options include `json_encode()` and `serialize()`. If the values have commas in them, they'll be ambiguous with `implode(', ', $fruits)`

Answer (score 1):

You will get result in array with name of your checkbox .In this case you will get like chk[0]=> , chk[1] => , and so on.. in $_POST array.

After that if u have to store it like  banana, mango, apple, orange then , do implode of that array using ',' separator..

```
implode(',' $_POST['chk'])
```